# Как обновить nodejs в Ubuntu 11.10 ?

Tags: node.js, javascript, ubuntu

Сейчас стоит версия 0.4.9. Как корректно обновить NodeJS до последней актуальной версии?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала убедитесь в том что у вас установлены пакет libssl-dev, если не установлен - ставьте.

```
 sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Качаете исходники с офф сайта, распаковываете в папку, открываете терминал:

```
cd папка_с_распакованными_файлами
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Спасибо, все прошло без ошибок, но при проверке версии node -v показывает старую 0.4.9. Как переключиться на новую?

Comment: Я так понимаю старая ставилась из репозитария? Если да то снесите через sudo apt-get и поставьте еще раз (ошибок не будет)

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) - очень удобно.

Comment: Благодарю, разобрался, с этого в общем-то и нужно было начинать)